# How @Value("#{servletContext.contextPath}") is resolved but @Value("${servletContext.contextPath}")

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot why `@Value("#{servletContext.contextPath}")` is resolved but `@Value("${servletContext.contextPath}")` isn't?

Answer (score 2):

`#{servletContext.contextPath}` evaluates expression using `servletContext` bean, resulting in a call to [`ServletContext.getContextPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()).

`${servletContext.contextPath}` resolves a property named `servletContext.contextPath` which normally is not present.

The SpEL is explained in details in Spring Framework docs, chapter [4. Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions).